# Conceptual question about universal generalization and the domain of discourse of our "arbitrary elements"

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

One of the concepts that I have had some difficulty fully comprehending is the deployment of *Universal Generalization* in proofs. Here is what I think I understand correctly.

Let's say that I want to prove some generic, universally quantified statement like $\forall x \varphi (x)$ with respect to some domain of discourse $\mathcal D$. I know that if I prove $\varphi(y)$ with respect to $\mathcal D$, where $y$ is a variable that has "*no assumptions placed on it"*, then I can conclude $\forall x \varphi (x)$ with respect to $\mathcal D$.

However, it appears to me that there **is**, implicitly, an assumption that *must* be placed on $y$: specifically, that $y$, although arbitrary, **must exist within $\mathcal D$.**

Therefore, at the outset of any proof strategy that invokes *Universal Generalization*, it seems like I always need to establish that my arbitrary $y$ resides within the domain of discourse.

Firstly, is this *correct*?

Secondly, how should one **formally** assert this?

The axiomatic framework that I have been recently working with is *ZFC*, and an easy example that I can think of that captures my above outline is the statement:

$\forall x (\emptyset \subseteq x)$ where $\varphi(x):=\emptyset \subseteq x$ ... or more formally: $\forall x \big (\forall z ( z \in \emptyset \rightarrow z \in x) \big )$

---

I would start this proof off by saying:

**Let $x'$ be an arbitrary element in our domain of discourse**.

Prove: $\forall z (z\in \emptyset \rightarrow z \in x')$.

Then I would say:

**Let $z'$ be an arbitrary element in our domain of discourse**.

Prove: $z' \in \emptyset \rightarrow z' \in x'$

etc etc.

My question is thus: What do I need to do to demonstrate that $x'$ and $z'$ are elements in our domain of discourse? What is the FOL justification that $x'$ and $z'$, in fact, reside within our domain of discourse?

Hopefully this question is sufficiently clear.

Cheers~

Comment: $x,y,z$ are variables, i.e. part of the language. Rules of inference manipulate formulas, that are expression of the language. "What is the FOL justification that x′ and z′, in fact, reside within our domain of discourse?" The **interpretation** of a FOL language in a domain $\mathcal D$ assumes that variables range over element of the domain.

Comment: Everything takes place inside the domain of discourse, that's what "domain of discourse" means. You don't have to prove that something is in the domain of discourse; rather, it doesn't even make sense to talk about something *not* in the domain of discourse.

Comment: For Universal Generalization, see [your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3856407/what-is-the-difference-between-proving-something-for-an-arbitrary-object-and-pro).

Comment: For "domain" see the post [Domains in First-order logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294137/domains-in-first-order-logic)

Comment: To add to above comments. That "$x$ is in the domain of discourse" means "$x$ is a set" or "$x$ is a natural number" or ... is an interpretational side-effect of the fact that you work within the axiom system of ZFC or within the Peano axioms or ... Indeed, every such axiom of the form $\forall y\phi(y)$ automatically applies to your arbitrary $x$, because via specialization $\forall y\phi(y)\vdash \phi(x)$., which forces $x$ to "behave" like a set or natural number or ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber  I maybe / sort of understand what you are saying. But that makes me think that all of my formal arguments that begin with (for example): "Let $x'$ be an arbitrary element in our domain of discourse"...should actually be phrased as "IF $x'$ is an arbitrary element of our domain of discourse, THEN etc etc". So, basically, my whole formal argument stems from this 'baseline' implication. Is this the wrong way of thinking about it?

Comment: @S.Cramer I wouldn't say "wrong," but it's a bit clunky. The point is that "... in our domain of discourse" is **already implicit in** "Let." We don't need to say "... in the domain of discourse," since our language only lets us refer to things in the domain of discourse by definition.

Comment: @NoahSchweber so does "Let $x'$ be an arbitrary element $+$ 'the following argument' " effectively amount to "IF we let $x'$ be an arbitrary element, THEN 'the following argument' "?

Comment: @S.Cramer Sure, I guess. The latter just seems weirdly clunky to me. The former more accurately reflects how variable introduction actually works on the syntax level.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think the reason the former way confuses me is because I don't see who the objective arbiter is that decides whether or not the statement "$x'$ is arbitrary" is true, and therefore I get weirdly uncomfortable working forwards from it.

Comment: @S.Cramer Arbitrariness isn't a property objects have or don't have. Semantically, $x'$ is "undetermined:" we're reasoning about what happens to *all* assignments of elements of the structure in question to variables. Intuitively it may help to think about $x'$ as an "unknown:" I tell you I have an element of the structure under consideration but I don't tell you what it is, and you have to reason from imperfect information about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some flexibility, i.e. you are not committed to a particular form of FOL*, then this problem could be avoided if all domains of quantification were may explicit as is usually the case in mathematical proofs. This would also allow different domains for different quantifiers even within the same statement.

If $D$ is your domain of quantification (a set in this case), then you would write universal generalizations in the form:

(1) $~~~~~~\forall x \in D: P(x)~~~~~~$OR$~~~~~~\forall x:[x\in D \implies P(x)]$

You would write existential generalizations in the form:

(2) $~~~~~~\exists x\in D: P(x)~~~~~~$OR$~~~~~~\exists x:[x\in D \land P(x)]$

To prove a statement of the form (1), you could start with an assumption that $x\in D$. Then it wouldn't matter if $D$ was empty or not. It would matter if you wanted to infer $P(x)$ from (1). Then $D$ would have to be non-empty.

---

$*$ If you are committed to a form of FOL that does not make the domain explicit on every quantifier, it may help to imagine all of this going on "behind the scenes" with the same unspecified, *non-empty* domain on every quantifier (as is the convention).